Taking screenshot programtically in android, but not visible in storage
I am have wrote the following code to take the screenshot in jetpakc compose. But  the file is not visible in the storage, can anybody please help me to identify what i am doing wrong..

Asking for media permission.
Get the rootview.
Storing it in a bitmap
Writing that to a file.

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            var isPermission by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            val context : Context = this
            val mediaStoragePermission = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                onResult = {isGranted ->
                    if(isGranted)
                    {
                        isPermission = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {mediaStoragePermission.launch(
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )

                }) {
                    Text(text = "Take ScreenShot")
                }
            }

            if(isPermission)
            {
                ScreenshotComponent()
            }

        }
    }
}

Screenshot component
@Composable
fun ScreenshotComponent() {
    val view = LocalView.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
        val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).applyCanvas {
            view.draw(this)
        }
        bmp.let {
            File(context.filesDir, "screenshot.png")
                .writeBitmap(bmp, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85)
        }
    }, 1000)
}

private fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
    outputStream().use { out ->
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, out)
        out.flush()
    }
}


Can you debug and tell what exception you are getting?

It should be saved in the app's data directory (/data/data/<yourapp>/files/screenshot.png). How have you verified that it isn't there?

@Leviathan it is not visible in this

How have you verified that it isn't there? When I look for it with the Device Explorer of Android Studio I can find it there.
